# Convert Decimal to Hex and store to array in C

Tags: c, hex, converters

I've been trying to convert decimal from 1 to 99 to hexadecimal and store them into an array.

What I have is something like this:

```
int main(){
int i =1;
char dump_holder[3];
char hex_holder[100];
for (i=1;i<100;i++){
    sprintf(dump_holder, "%02x",i);
    hex_holder[i] = atoi(dump_holder);
    printf("this: %02x\n", hex_holder[i]);

}
return 0;}
```

I'm getting correct value a certain number. This code returns:

```
this: 01
this: 02
this: 03
this: 04
this: 05
this: 06
this: 07
this: 08
this: 09
this: 00
this: 00
this: 00
this: 00
this: 00
this: 00
this: 0a
this: 0b
this: 0c
this: 0d
this: 0e
this: 0f
this: 10
this: 11
this: 12
this: 13
this: 01
this: 01
this: 01
this: 01
this: 01
this: 01
this: 14
this: 15
this: 16
this: 17
this: 18
this: 19
this: 1a
this: 1b
this: 1c
this: 1d
```

I think the stray values are the null terminator, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Wrong format specifier for char.

Comment: You are using [`atoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/) for converting a number in __hexadecimal__ representation to an `int`, but `atoi` is designed for converting a number in __decimal__ representation.

Comment: BTW what output do you expect? _I think the stray values are the null terminator_, no you think wrong.

Comment: @MartinJames I don't think that this is the problem here, see my first comment

Answer (score 1):

well, the basic thing is I cannot understand what you are actually trying to achive

but I will try my best:

```
int main(){
int i =1;
char dump_holder[3];
char hex_holder[100];
for (i=1;i<100;i++){
    /* convert numerical value to string */
    sprintf(dump_holder, "%02x",i); 

    /* convert string value back to numerical value */
    //hex_holder[i] = atoi(dump_holder); //won't work
    hex_holder[i] = strtol(dump_holder, NULL, 16); // this will

    /* print the numerical value in hex representation */
    printf("this: %02x\n", hex_holder[i]);
}
return 0;}
```

- are you trying to create a string representation of the values in hex format?
  if so, you are going about this the wrong way
- right now you are not doing much except wasting proccessing power

even so i added a small code that will actuallt conver the code to a string representation of the values. Maybe that is what you actually intended to do

```
int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    char dump_holder[3];

    /* the array should be an array of strings (restricted here to 2chars) */
    char hex_holder[100][2];

    for (i=1;i<100;i++){
        /* convert numerical value to string representation */
        sprintf(hex_holder[i], "%02x",i);
        /* print the string produced */
        printf("this: %s\n", hex_holder[i]);  
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` assumes decimal representation, try `strtol(dump_holder, NULL, 16);` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the problem in your code, you first need to understand -
How `atoi` works?

Read about `atoi` and go through the example demonstrating its behavior 
[here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi).

In your program output, after `09` you are getting six times `00` because the `atoi` is returning `0` for the hex values `0a`, `0b`, `0c`, `0d`, `0e` and `0f`.
After this the program output is:
`this: 0a
this: 0b
this: 0c
this: 0d
this: 0e
this: 0f`

Reason is -
The hex value after `0f` is `10`. `10` is stored in `dump_holder` variable which is passed to `atoi`.
`atoi` returned integer value `10` which is stored in `hex_holder[i]`.
Your program is printing the value stored in `hex_holder[i]`, which is of type `char`, using `%x` format specifier. So, the value `10` is getting printed as `0a`.

Using incorrect format specifier is undefined behavior which includes it may do exactly what the programmer intended or silently generating incorrect results or anything else.

Just to convert decimal from 1 to 99 to hexadecimal and store them into an array, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char hex_holder[100][3];
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        snprintf (hex_holder[i], 3, "%02x", i);
        printf("this: %s\n", hex_holder[i]);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```